# F# access Array ith element function Error

Tags: arrays, f#, element

I have several times used the expression `anArray.[i]` to access an element from an array.

but all the sudden when i try to make a very very simple function then i get an error.

```
let safeIndexIf anArray i =
  anArray.[i]
```

I need to make a function that returns the ith element of the array so i thought that was an easy one but no...

The Error:

The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints

Why is this not working? I dont know what the error means by that. All i know i have done something similar to this lots of times to access an element of anArray so why can't i this time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the compilers type inference cannot determine that `anArray` is indeed an array.

The error message is suggesting you add a type annotation, you could do something like this to say that `anArray` is a generic array:

```
let safeIndexIf (anArray : array<'a>) i =
    anArray.[i]
```

If you want to avoid type annotations you could try rewriting your function to use `Array.item` which has the same behaviour:

```
let safeIndexIf anArray i =
    Array.item i anArray
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense